# What happens if you don't hash a value before selecting a hash map bucket?

Tags: algorithm, hash

Since a hash map works with a modulus/division operation to select the appropriate bucket to place the value in, it seems that the chance of collision is dependent on the number of buckets, not "how good the hash function is". How good the function function is decides the likelihood of a same-hash return collision. However 'collision' in a hash map is referring to something else, it's referring to the same value AFTER the modulus operation. Assuming the key value is an integer (say 64 bit), what can be expected if the hash function for a hash map is simply the key value itself? I would venture to say that retrieval would be lot faster, as there wouldn't be a need to loop through a number of bytes and do hash operations, with an end result, with respect to hash table collisions, much the same. I mean, the exact values that end up colliding with an already occupied bucket are different values, but if the values are spread all over the place then overall the results should be very similar.

Comment: isn't it just a set?

Comment: Integer hashes don't have to do some slow byte-by-byte thing, they can (and probably should) be based on 32-bit or 64-bit integer operations. That still costs more than zero time, but I think you're making assumptions that are more pessimistic than necessary. It only takes a couple of steps to "mix up" an integer that way, see for example the "finalizer" of MurmurHash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since a hash map works with a modulus/division operation to select the appropriate bucket to place the value in, it seems that the chance of collision is dependent on the number of buckets, not "how good the hash function is". How good the function function is decides the likelihood of a same-hash return collision

Not quite. A poor hash function can cluster keys or make particular bits more likely than others to be set. That, in turn, can result in some buckets being more likely to be selected by the modulus operator.

> Assuming the key value is an integer (say 64 bit), what can be expected if the hash function for a hash map is simply the key value itself?

In general, you can't say. There could very well be patterns in the keys that, if you just used the modulus operator, will cause some buckets to be much more full than others. A good hashing function essentially randomizes the bits so you're more likely to evenly distribute the keys in the buckets.

Comment: I'm wondering about the likelihood of collision into the same bucket. If the initial hash "randomises the bits", then after doing the modulus operation the chance the result going into any of the n_buckets is one in n_buckets. That's the case whether you hash or not.

Comment: @Zebrafish No, that's not the case. For example, imagine your keys have only a small number of bit patterns in a particular place. That is, in bits 5-8 where there could be 16 possible bit patterns, only 2 or 3 of the possible bit patterns are represented. That will result in clustering of keys when you apply the modulus operator. Hashing will eliminate that kind of pattern, making clustering much less likely.

Answer (score 2):

> it seems that the chance of collision is dependent on the number of buckets, not "how good the hash function is

No, that is not correct.  Keys are not generally distributed evenly across bucket indexes.  Hashing keys tends to more evenly distribute the bucket index better than raw key.

```
index = key%bucket_n;
// vs
index = hash(key)%bucket_n;
```

Further: A good hash function works well with any `bucket_n`.  A weak hash function improves when `bucket_n` is a prime.

---

There is a need to balance the number of entries in a table vs. the table size.  If `entires_n` much less than `table_size`, OP assertions make some sense.  Yet this waste lots of memory

If `entires_n` much greater than `table_size`, collisions are common.  Often even worse without a hash function.

IMO, the hash table size should exponentially grow with the entry count to maintain a density less than some threshold, say 1/3.  A re-hash of the table may be needed to accommodate a size change.

Comment: "No, that is not correct. " Let's a do a thought experiment, bucket_n is 12, and we have a long list of sequential integers as keys. We do 0 % 12 and insert into bucket, 1 % 12 and insert into bucket. We would get a collision once every 12 times 1/12. Now you might say "but that's only for a sequential sequence". Well now imagine you hash every value first. When you hash the value you get a number, when you then do modulo 12 to that number the chance of it falling into one of the 12 buckets is 1 in 12, 1/12, SAME.  The way I see it the likelihood is the same.

Comment: @Zebrafish Agree if the number of buckets stays the same.  Better, as suggested to "grow with the entry count to maintain a density less than some threshold" such that a _long list_ triggers a complete re-hash to an exponentially growing table as the value grows

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming the key value is an integer (say 64 bit), what can be expected if the hash function for a hash map is simply the key value itself?

Many languages do exactly that. E.g. [Java](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l960).

But you have to be careful, if your hash function is too trivial, it would also be trivial for an attacker to exploit hash collisions to cause a DoS in your service. This is known as a [Collision Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack). Different libraries deal with that in different ways.

Java HashMap [falls back to a red-black tree](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l145) whenever it detects too many collisions in a single bucket. Other languages introduce randomization in the hash function, so it would be harder for an attack to exploit it.

Comment: Are you saying that the typical Java implementation of a hash map is simply to select a bucket based on the key % n_buckets, without doing any hashing of the key beforehand?

Comment: I'm saying that the implementation of `hashCode` for Integer in Java just returns the integer itself, without any further operations. Which (for integers) does exactly as you said.